# Android Button's textView set Using Switch statement

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  Button button1, button2, okbutton;
  ImageView imageView;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.letterbutton);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.letter2button);
    okbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.okbutton);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      }
    });
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      }
    });
    okbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      }
    });

    int number;
    Random random = new Random();
    number = random.nextInt(2) + 1;
    while (number > 0) {

      switch (number) {
      case 1:
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image_2);
        button1.setText("Pavel");
        button2.setText("robin");
        break;

      case 2:

        imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image_3);
        button1.setText("Galib");
        button2.setText("Rimon");
        break;

      }

      if (okbutton.isPressed()) {
        number = random.nextInt(2) + 1;
      }

    }
  }

}
```

When I run this apps nothing was show in my phone.
But there is no error message.
I want to do when I run this apps it shows random number's button and image.
When i pressed okbutton then random number will generate and it will shows that statment.
How I can do it please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok its cool...

copy the entire random + switch into the onClickListeners & remove while loop:
this way the app first loads up random value, and when clicked it will do it again :)

```
@Override
  public void onClick(View arg0) {
    int number;
Random random = new Random();
number = random.nextInt(2) + 1;


  switch (number) {
  case 1:
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image_2);
    button1.setText("Pavel");
    button2.setText("robin");
    break;

  case 2:

    imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image_3);
    button1.setText("Galib");
    button2.setText("Rimon");
    break;

  }

  if (okbutton.isPressed()) {
    number = random.nextInt(2) + 1;
  }
```

}

```
  }
```